# Why is my field initialized twice - error - Field has already been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization

I am using the 'package:theme_config/theme_config.dart';' to dynamically change the flutter app theme and some variables there are declared as `final`:

```
static late final Reader _read;
static late final SharedPreferences _preferences;
static late final ThemeProfile _profile;
```

Consequently, I get this error:

`Field '_read@504051772' has already been initialized`

Here is my main method:

```
void main() async{
  //* 2. Initialize the package
  await ThemeConfig.init(themeProfile);  
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(Phoenix(
    child:MyApp()));
}
```

I assume I am initializing the the `_reader` twice in the build method but I am unsure how to fix it.
Note: If I declare the members without `final` the error disappears:
`static late Reader _read;`

Still, I'd like to fix my build method instead of modifying the package. Any ideas?

Here is my build method.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final Store<AppState> store =
        Store<AppState>(appStateReducer, initialState: AppState.initialState());

    return StoreProvider<AppState>(
      store: store,
      child: StoreBuilder<AppState>(
          onInit: (store) => store.dispatch({}),
          builder: (BuildContext context, Store<AppState> store) => ThemeBuilder(
            builder: (theme) {
              return MaterialApp(
                theme: theme.light,
                darkTheme: theme.dark,
                themeMode: theme.mode,
                navigatorObservers: [ThemeConfig.routeObserver],
              );
            })),
    );
  }
```

The `_read` value is assigned in the `theme_buidler.dart` part of the package:

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   ThemeConfig._read = ref.read;
   ThemeConfig._initOverlay(refresh: () => mounted ? setState(() {}) : null);
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}
```

**UPDATE:** I didn't mention this before but I am also using Phoenix package to restart the app after logout, this is when I see the error:
`Phoenix.rebirth(context)`.

I am pretty sure it's what triggers the error...

This is the package:
`'package:flutter_phoenix/flutter_phoenix.dart';`

Comment: Where do you assign value to `_read`? I don't see in your code.

Comment: What does `AppState.initialState()` do?

Comment: I don't assign the value to `_read`  explicitly in my app. It's assgined in the `theme_buidler.dart` part of the package. I have updated my question with the relevant code.

Comment: `AppState.initialState()` creates the initial instance of a Redux Store: `(new) Store<AppState> Store(   AppState Function(AppState, dynamic) reducer, {   required AppState initialState,`.

Comment: I see, so the problem is likely within the package code, if you followed the instructions. I checked the package, it was updated 20 months ago. Unfortunately I can't help you with your issue, but as a rule of thumb it is better to avoid packages which were not updated for almost 2 years.

Comment: Thanks Peter, you are absolutely right about that. Unfortunately, this is the only package that works for my case, unless I want to write the theme code from scratch myself. I've updated my question now, it's probably not the package but the app restart method that I use - I believe it initializes the package for a second time.

Comment: @BradG You probably should make `Phoenix` be a child of `ThemeBuilder`.

Comment: I thought of that but Phoenix is called like so: `runApp(
    /// 1. Wrap your App widget in the Phoenix widget
    Phoenix(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );` . While `ThemeBuilder` is to be called in the build method.

Comment: @BradG Can't you do `runApp(ThemeBuilder(builder: (theme) => Phoenix(child: MyApp(theme))));` and change `MyApp` to pass `theme` through to `MaterialApp`?  Or change `MyApp`'s `build` method to `return ThemeBuilder(builder: (theme) => Phoenix(child: MaterialApp(theme: ...)));`?